# How to create a simple and browser independent tooltip?

Tags: jquery, html, css, youtube

I'm trying to create a tooltip like the one that youtube shows you when you hover over their "like" button, for example.

[image]

How can I achieve this in a simple and browser compatible way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for a tooltip plugin. Try [QTip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) (if you're using jQuery.)

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i was searching.

Comment: Oh and for people who can't find why it isn't working properly:
Make sure you include jquery before you include the tooltip js class....

Comment: +1, Qtip is AWESOME, especially now that it has themeroller support.  Upcoming props will be going to jQuery UI's tooltip when it's launched in the very near future as it's much leaner.

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring too is a tooltip.

Most commonly is this effect initiated by JavaScript, a vast majority requiring the jQuery, Mootools or Prototype -javascript libraries. There are probably ways of doing this with CSS as well, but these will have many compatibility issues across browsers

this list shows a lot of these plug-ins: http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-an-user-friendly-tooltip/

Comment: I removed the "Netherlands" version - try to post all answers/questions in English, as this is a _global_ website.

Comment: No problem, the image was in dutch so I thought why not. I will keep to this from now on. :)